# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS with Ninja framework on Heroku

Tags: java, ssl, heroku, https, ninjaframework

How to configure a Ninja web application running on Heroku to force the use of SSL, that is, redirect all requests to HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the class to add in the conf package:

```
public class Filters implements ApplicationFilters {
  @Override
  public void addFilters (List<Class<? extends Filter>> list) {
    list.add (HttpsFilter.class);
  }
  public static class HttpsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public Result filter (FilterChain filterChain, Context context) {
      if ("http".equals (context.getHeader ("X-Forwarded-Proto"))) {
        return Results.redirect ("https://" + context.getHostname ()
          + context.getRequestPath ());
      }
      return filterChain.next (context);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look good in the ninja framework documentation it is indicated how to configure it to get what you want

http://www.ninjaframework.org/documentation/configuration_and_modes.html

Comment: This does not tell me how to redirect http requests to https.

Comment: OK I guess I understand, do you want that when a user connects to port 80 you want to redirect him to the 443?

Comment: Yes you have guessed.

Comment: OK I think you should set it on your web server, is the most convenient and safe solution, whot is the name of your web server? (es: apache, tomcat, ecc..)

Comment: The Ninja app is hosted on Heroku.

Comment: Ok keroku uses its web server, in which case you can not edit the configuration files but i found keroku ti to generate the ssl certificate.But I noticed that it allows you to manage web server web confs, after generating and inserting them through their systems you just have to make sure the web contains:
 "IdentitiesOnly yes", LINK:https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't help, I don't have problems with SSH keys.

Comment: You have to insert this line into in the heroku configuration -> IdentitiesOnly yes